# How do I run a Flask application with React routing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, flask

I have a functional server, application.py. I also have a functional React website.

I'd like to have Flask run as a server, but allow React to do the routing. However, it's unclear how to get Flask to communicate with React in this way. Of course, simply routing to the .js files won't work after the build command is ran.

(I plan to deploy on Elastic Beanstalk.)

It works fine with a NodeJs server but I'm not sure how to get it to work with Flask.